# How Undo Work in Editors

Tags: java

I am designing my own Editor like Notepad in Java. I have used `JEditorPane` in the writing of text. I don't know how the Undo work in Editors. How can I maintain the previous state of the text which is written by the user in the `JEditorPane`.

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: You should provide some code and/or make your question more specific because there are many many ways you could do this.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the [Memento Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) to make this undo feature. Wikipedia has an example in Java to help you out.

Basically you can keep a stack of states of the program. To 'undo', you can simply set the current state of the program (or text area in this case) to a previous state.

Comment: Is it good to save all the content each time?? Could I save only the changes?....